# How to tell which third-party app called startActivity into my app

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, start-activity

Suppose there are two apps on my device, GoodApp and EvilApp.  I didn't write either of them.  Both apps can use an ACTION_SEND Intent to start an exported activity in my app, passing data in.  They both call startActivity, *not* startActivityForResult.

I want to trust the data I receive from GoodApp, but distrust and ignore the data I receive from EvilApp.

How can my Activity tell which app started it?  Activity.getCallingActivity() returns null, because it wasn't started for-result.  I can't send a message back to the apps asking "was it you who sent me this?" because they aren't written to respond to that, and their code is out of my control.  Is there any way I can tell the difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Require apps use `startActivityForResult` in order for you to handle their request? (:

[ActivityManager.getRunningTasks](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRunningTasks(int)) might give you a hint, but its documentation says not to use it for things like what you are asking.